# How to search for value in text which is starting and ending with the same symbol but the numbers between are different every time? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to search, find and keep only the numbers of a specific string inside a text message, the value always starts with **<@** and ends with **>**. Its **str** is always **21**, the numbers between **<@** and **>** are changing every time and the position is not fixed, it can be anywhere in the text message.

---

What I'm doing now:

```
if (message.content.includes('<@')) {
  let numberPattern = /\d+/g;
  let onlyNumbers = message.content.match(numberPattern).toString();
  ...
```

If the text is like:

> Hello <@371362419361972245> how are you?

The **onlyNumbers** var will be, correctly:

```
371362419361972245
```

But if the text is like:

> Hello <@371362419361972245> h0w 4r3 y0u?

The **onlyNumbers** var will be:

```
3713624193619722450430
```

---

What I want to do is to keep only the numbers between <@ and >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex would be a good application of this.  For future references, a good tool to scaffold your regexes is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

The regex you want looks like

```
/<@(\d+)>/
```

If you want to support multiple such instances of that pattern in a single string, you could add the `g` flag at the end of that pattern.

To determine the numbers between the `<@` and `>` characters, use [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), which will return an array that looks something like:

```
[
    "<@371362419361972245>",  // The full string that matched the pattern
    "371362419361972245",     // The first (and only) matching group
]
```

If you want to support the `g` flag, you would execute the same method over the same string multiple times until it returned null.